# Is there an upper limit on model size in Mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I get the following error when trying to open my mwb model file

```
error unserializing grt data 
string to long
```

My file is 217 KB and I am using version 6.3.4.0 build 828 for 64 bit windows  community edition

Last thing I did before saving it was adding some tables.   Did not add any long names, comments or anything like that

The model file has 100++ tables and 10+ diagrams showing these.

Is this a bug, corrupt model file  or is there a upper limit on the size of models ?

Comment: I've got the same problem on 32-bit with the fresh installed same version. I'm downgrading.

Comment: You know, my problem was gone when I reopened workbench )))

Comment: Tried reopning before posting with no luck. 
 
Found an older backup file and worked on with that.  The model size (num tables, num diagrams ec) has now passed what it was when it the file failed.

So guess my problem was a corrupt file for some unknown reason.  

But the question still stands, are there an upper limit on the model, and what are these if so.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem, Just close and open it, it will be solved, This bug is in several versions

Answer (score 4):

I had just run into this error, recently...To solve this problem, do the following:

1) Close out the program.

2) Locate and Open the MySQL Work Bench (.mwf) file with MySQL Workbench.

I learned this from my professor, and while it seems like a bit much, that's how I got my Database Table Schema to display properly again.

To be honest, this clearly must be a bug in the programming software; Might I suggest downgrading your product to one that doesn't have this bug in it, if this bothers you too much?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is **not** the upper limit size of the model and to solve your issue just exit MySQL Workbench and reopen it. I had faced this issue with the ***6.3 version Community 64 Bit Windows***.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem and searched through the internet and found an easy solution.
 instead of closing the whole workbench application and open it again, as suggested by other answers, I just closed the '*local instance MYSQL57*' tab and opened the my **.mwb** file. The file has opened with no errors!.
It seems that this is a bug in the workbench and it has been reported by other users.
We hope that this issue would be resolved in the next releases of the workbench.
Hope this help..,